# Retrieving information of a ForeignKey in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I’m new to DRF - would appreciate some help here.

I’ve a model relationship like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name=“books”)
    ..

class Chapter(models.Model)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name=“chapters”)
    ..
```

While creating a new Book, I can link to the User by accessing the information from `request.user` and by overriding `perform_create`.

How can I achieve the similar behaviour while creating a new `Chapter`, i.e. getting the foreign key `Book`? I understand that it can be passed through the request parameters but I’m unable to find out how to let a user provide the `Book` ID/name in a POST request and linking it to the newly created `Chapter`.

My serializer looks like this:

```
class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
```

And the view is:

```
class ChapterList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChapterSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Chapter.objects.filter(book__in=Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the book already exists when you want to create a new Chapter I thing the best way would be to use a url where you specify the bookid like this:

```
url(r'^books/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/chapters/$', ChapterList.as_view(), name='api_chapters'),
```

This way you can get the book instance and link the chapter to it.
In the view you can get the book id like this:

```
book_id = kwargs.get('pk')
```